# $B$ and $H$ fields at boundary of two media

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits

i was reading about magnetic circuits with air gaps and found that H in the gap (Hg) and H in the core of the magnetic material (Hc) were different, but the B field was equal throught (since flux will be same, and fringing effect is neglected and hence area of cross section will be same). This made little sense, that whereas H fields change on crossing the medium interface, B remained same.
Upon reading further in a book by IE Irodov- basic laws of electromagnitism, it said

> 'The lines of **B** do not have a discontinuity upon transition
> through the interface, while the **H** lines do (due to the surface
> magnetization currents)"

(page 144)
Can someone explain what these surface magnetization current are?

Also i have shown a loop 1 in the picture attatched, as in this loop the lower leg is in the core, hence **H** is present, and H.l shoudl not be equal to zero, then what is the enclosed current? [image]

Comment: have you heard of the concepts and difference between free and bound currents? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law

Comment: I was brought up to believe that H was a field and B was a flux-density.  With that in mind, you then have to ask, if B were discontinuous at the interface where would that extra flux go?  I don't think the concept of "lines" is very helpful. I often resort to analogies with water flow where H (or E) correspond to pressure gradient down the pipe and B (or D) correspond to flow.

Comment: The flux isnt going anywhere as B is flux density and not flux. And flux density can "change"?